# How to get value at a point of line extended - TradingView Pine script

Tags: charts, pine-script, trading

Im using the code below to draw a line:

```
//@version=4

simplesma = sma(close, 14)

var line3 = line.new(bar_index[0], high[0], bar_index, low, extend = extend.right)
line.set_xy1(line3, bar_index[5], simplesma[5])
line.set_xy2(line3, bar_index[3], simplesma[3])
```

That line has been drawn using 2 points in the history.

And then I use this code to draw a plot

```
price_point = line.get_price(line3,bar_index)
plot(price_point, title='Price', color=#ffcc00, transp=30)
```

Im trying to display the value on a label but the following code does not work:

```
var label3 = label.new(bar_index, high, text = "Value: "+ tostring(price_point, "#.########"), style = label.style_label_lower_left, color=#ffcc00, textcolor=#ff0000)
label.set_xy(label3,bar_index, price_point)
```

Can you please help me to show it on label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `price_point` is the value at the current bar (bar_index). You don't need to use the function `tostring()`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it.

```
var label3 = label.new(bar_index, high, text = "", style = label.style_label_lower_left, color=#ffcc00, textcolor=#ff0000)
label.set_xy(label3,bar_index, price_point)
label.set_text(label3, "Value: "+ tostring(price_point, "#.########"))
```